# Logarithm of $ei$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

> Find the logarithm of $ei$.

Firstly we know that the log of a nonzero complex number $re^{i\theta} = r\cos(\theta) + ir\cos(\theta)$ is $\log(re^{i\theta}) = \log r + i\theta$. However, I do not know how to necessarily isolate the $i$ in this given context. Can anyone help me?

Comment: $ln(ei)=lne+lni$, do you know how to do $lni$?

Comment: If $r*e^{i\theta} = ei$ what is $r$ and what is $\theta$?

Answer (score 3):

Since $e^z$ has period $2\pi i$ in $\mathbb{C}$, we have that for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $$\text{Log}(e\cdot i)=\text{Log}(e)+\text{Log}(e^{i(2k\pi+\pi/2)})=1+i\pi\left(2k+\frac12\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\ln ei = \ln e + \ln i$

$\ln e = 1$

And $\ln i = \ln re^{i\theta}$ where $re^{i\theta} = i$.

$re^{i\theta} = r(\cos \theta) + i \sin \theta) = 1(0 + i*1)$ so

$r = 1; \cos \theta = 0$ and $\sin \theta = 1$.  So $\theta = \frac \pi 2 + 2k\pi$.

So $e*i = e*e^{i(\frac \pi 2 + 2k\pi)}$

And $\ln e*i = 1 + \frac {\pi i}2 + 2ki\pi$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* There is no necessity to isolate $e$ and $i$. We recall the general form \begin{align*}
z=a+ib=re^{i\theta}
\end{align*}

> Here we have
>   \begin{align*}
> z=e\cdot i=0+ie
> \end{align*}
>   with $a=0$ and $b=e$.

This implies that $e\cdot i$ is an imaginary number with real part $0$ and so $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ .

> We recall $\log(z)=\log(r)+i\theta$ and conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\log (ei)}=\log(e)+i\frac{\pi}{2}\color{blue}{=1+i\frac{\pi}{2}}.
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$e.i=e.e^{i \pi/2}$$
Then
$$
\log\left(e.i\right)=1+i\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: if you go multivalued: $1+i\pi\left(2n+\frac12\right)$ for integer $n$